# How to Dockerize a React-Django project where the frontend is served from Django?

Tags: reactjs, django, docker, django-rest-framework, monolithic

I'm new to Docker. I have been surfing through the internet to find any resources for how to Dockerize a React-Django project, in which the React App is served from Django, both running on port 8000, but couldn't find any proper resource for this. Can someone help me with the procedure for Dockerizing a React-Django project having a monolithic architecture?

Comment: And what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: When both React and Django are running independently, we create 2 containers in docker, one for React(which runs on port 3000) and for Django (which runs on port 8000). In my project, I have included the React built version of the app in the settings.py file, in the templates section. So, when I give the command python manage.py runserver, both my react app and Django run on port 8000. So in this case, should I just be creating a docker container only for my Django project?

Comment: Short answer, Yes!

Comment: If you're having an issue with the docker container or any other issue, update the question and we can workout the solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68241778/15964669. Tried to Dockerize my Django project. Faced an issue similar to this stack overflow discussion

Comment: whats the issue you faced?